# Why doesn't a SWF file in C# pause when using AxShockwaveFlash

Tags: c#, .net, flash, axshockwaveflash

I need to play various swf files in a C# application.

They seem to start playing fine but trying to pause it has no effect the 1st time and whites out the panel if I try again.

The code I'm using is below.

Also rewind & forward have no effect.

Any comments or help would be appreciated.

David Knight

```
namespace MyUI
{
    public partial class ABWithSWF : MyAbstractABFrm
    {
        // Keep Track of whats happening
        enum StateOfPlay {NotSet, Playing, Paused };

        private AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash axShockwaveFlashCube = new AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash();

        StateOfPlay playState = StateOfPlay.NotSet;

        public ABWithSWF()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pnlSwf.Controls.Add(axShockwaveFlashCube);
            axShockwaveFlashCube.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        // One button that is either play or pause
        private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // File to play
            string path = string.Format(@"{0}\graphical summary.swf", Utils.GetSWFPath());

            switch (playState)
            {
                case StateOfPlay.Paused:
                    axShockwaveFlashCube.Play();
                    btnPlay.ImageIndex = 3;
                    playState = StateOfPlay.Playing;
                    break;
                case StateOfPlay.Playing:
                    axShockwaveFlashCube.StopPlay();
                    btnPlay.ImageIndex = 4;
                    playState = StateOfPlay.Paused;
                    break;
                case StateOfPlay.NotSet:
                    axShockwaveFlashCube.LoadMovie(0, path);
                    axShockwaveFlashCube.Play();
                    btnPlay.ImageIndex = 4;
                    playState = StateOfPlay.Playing;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axShockwaveFlashCube.Rewind();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axShockwaveFlashCube.Forward();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just developed a project in c# to embed a flash object into an WPF UserControl, which has to embedd a Windows Forms UserControl to be able to play it.

So, my experience is that **Stop()** methd of the axShockwaveFlashObjects **is actually pausing** the movie and **Play() is actually resuming** the movie (also is starting it).

Here is the code I use in my Windows Forms UserControl to Play, Pause, Resume and Stop an swf object:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts playing the movie, or resumes
    /// it if it is paused.
    /// </summary>
    public void Play()
    {
        Stop();
        flash_control.Play();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pauses the movie. To resume it, 
    /// call <see cref="Play()"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public void Pause()
    {
        flash_control.Stop();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops playing the movie
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        flash_control.Stop();
        flash_control.FrameNum = 0;
    }
```